# Cannot get value inside object in my angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

So I have this code in my controller:

```
$scope.loadContacts = function () {
  $scope.contacts = [];
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    var options = {};
    options.multiple = true;
    $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(function (allContacts) {
      for (var i = 0; i < allContacts.length; i++) {
        var contact = allContacts[i];
        if (contact.phoneNumbers != null)
          $scope.contacts.push(contact);
      }
    }, function (error) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    })
  });
}
```

So I have no errors on that code. In my template:

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="c in contacts">{{c.displayName}} - {{c.phoneNumbers}}
</ion-item>
```

And the output:

[image]

As you can see, it works though I'm getting objects. So I tried

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="c in contacts">{{c.displayName}} - {{c.phoneNumbers.value}} // .value since I want to get the cellphone numbers
</ion-item>
```

But no luck. Im getting an empty list meaning it has errors. How can I properly access the cellphone number in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phoneNumbers is an array, if you want to get the phone Numbers acccess the first object , this should work

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="c in contacts">{{c.displayName}} - {{c.phoneNumbers[0].value}} </ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you! So can I still json stringify it?

Comment: on which part can I? directly in the variable?